# How to use the "equilibrium favors reactants" symbol in Microsoft Word?

Tags: equilibrium

Is there a Unicode symbol or any other way to insert the symbols "equilibrium favors reactants" and "equilibrium favors products" as text?

I have been looking online for a while and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer: I assume you're referring to the symbols $\ce{<=>>}$ and $\ce{<<=>}$. I don't believe these are included in unicode, but there are some similar ones that I believe are IUPAC acceptable replacements, which use full arrows instead of harpoons. These are

unicode 2942: ⥂

unicode 2943: ⥃

unicode 2944: ⥄

An alternative is to use a LaTeX package such as mhchem.